# Should we avoid square root solutions to differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx} &= \frac{y}{2x} \\ 
\frac{dy}{y} &= \frac{1}{2x} dx \\ 
\int\frac{1}{y} dy &=\int\frac{1}{2x} dx \\
\ln|y| &= \frac{1}{2} \ln|x| + C \\ 
y&=Ce^{\frac{1}{2}\ln|x|}=Ce^{\ln|x^\frac{1}{2}|}=C\sqrt{x}
\end{align}$$

My book gets a different answer. Namely, $y^2=Cx$. Is there some reason why we would want to avoid a square root in our answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is only for aesthetical reasons because $y^2=Cx$ looks slightly prettier that $y=C\sqrt{x}$. Since your $C$ is an arbitrary one can set the square root of the one $C$ within the text book solution equal to your $C$.